# Оптимальный способ прохода скользящим окном по DataFrame создавая нормализованный список

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Мне нужно пройтись по DataFrame плавающим окном и данные в этом окне нормализовать, используя максимум и минимум этого окна.

Результат хочу записать в новый столбец в виде списка. Вот исходная схема для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из выделенного окна при нормализации я получаю вот такой набор нормализованных векторов:

```
[[0.2714285714285714, 0.4314285714285715, 0.7285714285714285, 0.20285714285714285], 
[0.15714285714285714, 0.24857142857142855, 0.7057142857142856, 0.08857142857142858], 
[0.08857142857142858, 0.06571428571428571, 0.6828571428571428, 0.02], 
[0.8885714285714286, 0.98, 0.7971428571428572, 0.8200000000000001], 
[0.15714285714285714, 0.24857142857142855, 0.7057142857142856, 0.08857142857142858]]
```

Вот то, что я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже мой код, который я хотел бы оптимизировать и, по возможности, использовать возможности Pandas и постараться избежать итераций.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать с минимальным количеством итераций?

```
# Создаю демо-датафрейм
x = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x**2+8, "B": x*8, "C": x+34, "D": (x*x)+5})

repr_select = 5 # размер окна в строках
# вычисляю минимум и максимум для каждой итерации окна
df['Mini'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].rolling(repr_select).min().min(axis='columns')
df['Maxi'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].rolling(repr_select).max().max(axis='columns')

# Функция нормализации
# принимает на вход список чисел 
# возвращает нормализованный список чисел
def norn(massiv):
# пороговые значения для нормализации
  min_n = 0.02
  max_n = 0.98
  lst = []
  
  for n in massiv:
    norm = (n - minimum) * (max_n - min_n) / (maximum - minimum) + min_n
    lst.append(norm)
  return lst
        
# прохожусь по всему датафрейму и применяю функцию нормализации
for i in range(len(df)):
  mas = []

# проверяю дошло ли окно до последней строки?
  if i+repr_select <= len(df):
    minimum = df.loc[repr_select+i-1, 'Mini']
    maximum = df.loc[repr_select+i-1, 'Maxi']
    # Получаю массив чисел из скользящего окна
    win = df.iloc[i:i+repr_select, :4].values

    # добавляю в новый столбец весь уже нормализованный массив
    for s in win:
      mas.append(norn(s))
    df.loc[repr_select+i-1, 'lst_norm'] = str(mas)
    
      """
      Я записал весь набор векторов в одну ячейку, 
      но по хорошему нужно записывать каждое значение в новую ячейку. 
      Я просто не нашел такого способа распределения в Pandas.
      """
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно сделать так:

```
In [50]: (df.loc[:, 'A':'D']
            .sub(df['Mini'], axis=0)
            .mul(max_n - min_n)
            .div(df['Maxi']-df['Mini'], axis=0)
            .add(min_n))
Out[50]:
           A         B         C         D
0        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4   0.110000  0.080000  0.890000  0.020000
5   0.888571  0.980000  0.797143  0.820000
6   0.157143  0.248571  0.705714  0.088571
7   0.980000  0.863636  0.543636  0.936364
8   0.180000  0.281818  0.470909  0.136364
9   0.126667  0.020000  0.473333  0.086667
10  0.140000  0.126667  0.486667  0.100000
11  0.180000  0.233333  0.500000  0.140000
12  0.253514  0.227568  0.928108  0.175676
13  0.812000  0.980000  0.956000  0.740000
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Могли бы вы пояснить что за переменные `(max_n - min_n)` ?

Comment: пороговые значения для нормализации из вашего вопроса

Comment: немного не то что я ищу. Напротив каждого шага скользящего окна должен появляться нормализованный вектор. В моем примере, когда окно доходит до 6 строки к текущему датафрейму добавляется list: `[[0.2714285714285714, 0.4314285714285715, 0.7285714285714285, 0.20285714285714285], 
[0.15714285714285714, 0.24857142857142855, 0.7057142857142856, 0.08857142857142858], 
[0.08857142857142858, 0.06571428571428571, 0.6828571428571428, 0.02], 
[0.8885714285714286, 0.98, 0.7971428571428572, 0.8200000000000001], 
[0.15714285714285714, 0.24857142857142855, 0.7057142857142856, 0.08857142857142858]]`

Comment: Т.е. в результате вы хотите получить 3D матрицу из 2D?

Comment: К сожалению не понимаю термина 3D. По сути мне нужно шаг №1. данные из этого окна преобразовать в список, а шаг №2 полученный список нормализовать. Вот я еще один вопрос задал, как сделать первый шаг: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935535/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8
Может так будет проще?

Comment: Вы решили в ветке задачу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935535/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/935613?noredirect=1#comment1553163_935613 - она закрывает первый шаг. Во втором шаге я хочу нормализовать полученный вектор данных применив свою функцию `def norn(massiv):`.

Comment: @Mavar, а в чем теперь проблема? вроде бы теперь должно все получиться...