# Как разложить данные из скользящего окна в строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Я хочу пройтись по DataFrame скользящим окном и данные из этого окна разложить по столбцам рядом.

Вот демо-набор:

```
x = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x**2+8, "B": x*8, "C": x+34, "D": (x*x)+5})

# размер окна в строках
repr_select = 4 

df
```

Получаю вот такой датасет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно передвигаться по таблице скользящим окном и раскладывать данные, попавшие в фокус этого окна, в столбцы, напротив последней строки в этом окне.

Для понимания привожу схему того, что хочу получить:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важное дополнение: Количество столбцов в таблице может меняться. Также как и размер скользящего окна (в строках) тоже может меняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fun(win, df):
    data = np.full((df.shape[0], win*df.shape[1]), np.nan)
    for i in range(win, len(df)):
        data[i] = df.iloc[i-win:i].values.ravel()
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=df.index)

res = df.join(fun(4, df))
```

результат:

```
In [110]: res
Out[110]:
     A   B   C   D     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
0    9   8  35   6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   24  32  38  21   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   17  24  37  14   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   12  16  36   9   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    9   8  35   6   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  24.0  32.0  38.0  21.0  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0
5   44  48  40  41  24.0  32.0  38.0  21.0  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0
6   12  16  36   9  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  44.0  48.0  40.0  41.0
7   72  64  42  69  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  44.0  48.0  40.0  41.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0
8   17  24  37  14   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  44.0  48.0  40.0  41.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0  72.0  64.0  42.0  69.0
9    8   0  34   5  44.0  48.0  40.0  41.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0  72.0  64.0  42.0  69.0  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0
10   9   8  35   6  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0  72.0  64.0  42.0  69.0  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0   8.0   0.0  34.0   5.0
11  12  16  36   9  72.0  64.0  42.0  69.0  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0   8.0   0.0  34.0   5.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0
12   9   8  35   6  17.0  24.0  37.0  14.0   8.0   0.0  34.0   5.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0
13  33  40  39  30   8.0   0.0  34.0   5.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0  12.0  16.0  36.0   9.0   9.0   8.0  35.0   6.0
```

Comment: Как же у вас здорово получается! Это то что нужно! 
Скажите, а как можно присоединить получившийся датафрейм `res` к исходному датафрейму `df`, прямо как на схеме, чтобы один был объект?

Comment: @Mavar, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без `pandas`.

Представим ваш `x` как список значений некоторой длины

```
value_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Фрейм можно представить как набор некоторых функций например:

```
func_list = [lambda x: x**2, lambda w: w+1]
```

Обозначим значение как уложить строки например пусть 4:

```
repr_select = 4
```

По сути нам нужно проитерировать `value_list`, но по особенному - поместить значение в определённую функцию и выстроить результаты в определённую линию - создадим для этого пользовательский класс:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, fl, rs):
        self.item_len = rs
        self.line = fl*(rs/len(fl))
        self.arg = []
        self.fill = False

    def add_value(self, val):
        self.arg.append(val)
        if len(self.arg) == self.item_len:
            self.fill = True

    def calc(self):
        return [a(b) for a, b in zip(self.line, self.arg)]
```

Приступать к вычислениям имеет смысл если длина линии делится на количество функции без остатка. Потом создаём элемент класса - идём по списку наполняем, когда заполнился вычисляем и отправляем в список результат:

```
if repr_select % len(func_list) == 0:
    result = []
    ii = Item(func_list, repr_select)
    for value in value_list:
        if ii.fill:
            result.append(ii.calc())
            ii = Item(func_list, repr_select)
        ii.add_value(value)
    if len(ii.arg) != 0:
        result.append(ii.calc())
    print result
# [[1, 3, 9, 5], [25]]
```